# Formula Condicional

Tags: excel, formato-condicional

Tengo esta formula creada pero al actualizar datos no me cambian a la fecha correspondiente que debería ser:

```
=SI(I23>=FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));"FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23))";"PENDIENTE")
```

Comment: Bienvenido Geovanny, ¿podrías decirnos si la fórmula te devuelve algún error? ¿Podrías además ponernos algún ejemplo de lo que esperas que te devuelva la fórmula?

Comment: La formula en si no me develve ningun error, sucede que al actualizar la celda de la columna I23 por ejemplo en la celda de la columna J no introduce la fecha del mes siguiente FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));    Por ejemplo si tengo 17/04/2019 en la columna I en la columna J deberia aparecer 17/05/2019 que estaria dentro de la fecha actual que es hoy. Pero si no esta dentro de la fecha actual me pondria "Pendiente"

Comment: No te va a dar nunca `VERDADERO` porque la fecha que estás evaluando le sumas un mes siempre, tenga lo que tenga la celda `I`. Tu expresión  `=FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23))` siempre tendrá un mes más que la fecha que evalúas, salvo que yo no te esté entendiendo.

Comment: Realizando con dos SI tambien tengo el problema que es el mismo que dices. =SI(I23>=FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));SI(I23<FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));1;0);"PENDIENTE")            Lo que quiero es dos caminos verdadero y falso que sea verdadero me suelte la fecha del mes siguiente que este dentro de la fecha actual y si no esta dentro de la fecha actual que me suelte Pendiente

Comment: Sin datos de prueba está difícil revisar lo que pasa. Y por favor, la información adicional de la pregunta va en la pregunta, no en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Al ver la pregunta y los comentarios que se han acotado, siento decir que siempre el condicional imprimirá `Pendiente` como bien lo ha indicado @David. No obstante lo anterior, creo entender porque tampoco se obtendría esta fecha `17/05/2019` si se le adiciona un mes a `17/04/2019` directamente.

Mírese la siguiente tabla:

```
         I             J          K              L
#22 |   Fecha       limiteSuper limiteInf   ¿En el Intervalo?
23 | 17/04/2019          43602       43541     VERDADERO
24 | 17/04/2019     17/05/2019  17/05/2019       FALSO
25 | 17/04/2019       17/05/19    17/05/19       FALSO
24 | 17/04/2019       17/05/19    17/05/19       FALSO
```

Las fórmulas que se han empleado para lo anterior son estas:

```
           J
#22 | limiteSuper
23 | =FECHA.MES(I23;1)
24 | =TEXTO(FECHA.MES(I24;1);"dd/mm/aaaa")
25 | =FECHA(AÑO(I25);MES(I25)+1;DIA(I25))
26 | =FECHANUMERO(TEXTO(FECHA.MES(I26;1);"dd/mm/aaaa"))

         K
#22 | limiteInf
23 | =FECHA.MES(I23;-1)
24 | =TEXTO(FECHA.MES(I24;1);"dd/mm/aaaa")
25 | =FECHA(AÑO(I25);MES(I25)+1;DIA(I25))
26 | =FECHANUMERO(TEXTO(FECHA.MES(I26;1);"dd/mm/aaaa"))

              L
#22 | ¿En el Intervalo?
23 | =Y(I23<=J23;I23>=K23)
24 | =Y(I24<=J24;I24>=K24)
25 | =Y(I25<=J25;I25>=K25)
26 | =Y(I26<=J26;I26>=K26)
```

Es decir, para que **Excel** pueda comparar (`>,<,<>,=,..`) correctamente una fecha, ésta tiene que ser un número como tal, lo cual se hace bien con la función `FECHA`.

El formato de la misma se puede lograr con la función `TEXTO` o también en la misma celda aplicando `Formato de celdas` sí ésta debe ser trabajada para comparar rangos.

```
        B                C            
1 | FECHA            FORMATOS   FORMULAS EN LA COLUMNA 'C'
2 | 17/04/2019          43602   =FECHA.MES(B2;1)
3 | 43602          17-mayo-19   =TEXTO(B3;"d-mmmm-a")
4 | 43602     viernes-mayo-19   =TEXTO(B4;"ddddd-mmmm-a")
5 | 43602       mayo 17, 2019   =TEXTO(B5;"mmmm d, aaaa")
6 | 43602          2019-05-17   =TEXTO(B6;"aaaa-mm-dd")
7 | 43602          17/05/2019   =TEXTO(B7;"dd/mm/aaaa")
```

En tal sentido, para la fórmula que se expone inicialmente sería así (Pero se obtendrá siempre `Pendiente`)

```
=SI(I23>=FECHA.MES(I23;1);TEXTO(FECHA.MES(I23;1);"dd/mm/aaa");"PENDIENTE")
```

En todo caso, si estás comparando la fecha actual con respecto a la fecha que tienes en la celda `I23`, puedes usar la función `HOY()` pero empleando el operador menor o igual que (`<=`) ya que de esta forma se indicará, si está fuera de fecha dicha actividad y por tanto `Pendiente`.

```
=SI(HOY()<=FECHA:ES(I23;1);TEXTO(FECHA:ES(I23;1);"dd/mm/aaa");"PENDIENTE")
```

Finalmente la función [FECHA.MES](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/fecha-mes-funci%C3%B3n-fecha-mes-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5) que se ha empleado, también es útil si se quiere agregar años... sólo basta trabajar en múltiplos de 12 para tal caso, por ejemplo que día de la semana será de acá (17-abr-2019) a 7 años:

```
=TEXTO(FECHA.MES(HOY();12*7);"ddddd")
`Se imprime: Viernes
```

Lo mismo en sentido inverso que día fue hace 7 años: reemplazar `12*7` por `-12*7`

Answer (score 0):

Tu fórmula está mal planteada. Estás comparando una celda con sigo misma, más un mes. Debes utilizar una celda, por ejemplo I22, para Fecha1 e I23 para la Fecha2. También has de quitar las comillas del campo ValorSiVerdad ya que no es un string lo que quieres presentar.

```
=SI(I22>=FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));"PENDIENTE")
```

La celda destino debe estar formateada en fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, estás utilizando una fórmula que siempre será falsa. Lo que entiendo es que estás haciendo un condicional de que si la fecha en `I23` es mayor o igual a la misma fecha pero dentro de un mes. Si es así, esto siempre devolverá `False`.

`=SI(I23>=FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));FECHA(AÑO(I23);MES(I23)+1;DIA(I23));"PENDIENTE")`

Si deseas que en `J23` se muestre el mes siguiente al día mostrado en `I23`, te recomendaría usar la siguiente fórmula.

`=si(I23<=hoy();fecha.mes(i23;1);"Pendiente")`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con eso ya he podido completar mi formula